# Admin->System->Index Management shows Reindex Required

Tags: magento2

Installed Magento 2.1.7 Community Edition, created [cron jobs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg), but I still get **Reindex Required** on Indexed rule/product association.  What have I done wrong?

Note: When I do `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` I get the responses:

[image: Error messages for Magento 2 reindex]

Comment: Could you please  run reindex  command in ssh . Also double check the Cron jobs are working fine

Comment: check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html

Comment: Rama, please make your comment an answer - I had the wrong path to PHP, as noted in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your MySQL service not started.
If you are using xampp, then need to start MySQL service before run Indexer Command.

Comment: No.  If I wasn't running MySQL, the site wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Ok, Then It's missing, the PDO mysql connector reports SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

If you are continually getting this error thrown and have no access to Magento aside from the Exception Error page, then mysql has crashed completely and you need your hosting provider to find out why and restart mysql.

Comment: No.  [Rama Chandran](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/44702/rama-chandran) had the correct answer, as noted in the comments above.